# Content slide on app bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

In my android app I want the toolbar to stay fixed and the content of the activity slide over it, how can I achieve this effect?

Comment: The same effect as if you were using the new backdrop design component (like the sample app Shrine in MDC codelabs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So , just create layout named `your_activity_name` and past this code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    //your main content here

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

For more information check this link http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator